# I dont know why fopen not working? I need help to fix it

Tags: c

When i run my code, it returns "ERROR" in terminal. Basically fopen not work, and arq receive NULL. The "leitura.txt" is a file only to be read.

```
#include <stdio.h>
    
    int main(){
        FILE * arq = NULL;
        char c;
        int x;
        arq = fopen( "leitura.txt", "r" );
        if (arq == NULL){
            printf ("ERROR\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        while (fscanf(arq, "%c", &c) != EOF){
            printf("%c", c);
        }
        x = ftell(arq);
        printf("NUMBER OF BYTES: %d", x);
        fclose(arq);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I have tried to include stdlib.h for NULL but it won't working.

Comment: Sanity check: does the file exist in the same directory as your .c file? Also, here's the fopen reference: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/

Comment: print out the value of errorno

Comment: Yes, the file is on .c directory.

Comment: Be aware that files are opened relative to the *runtime* current directory, which may be different than the compile-time directory or the location of the executable.

Comment: I've tried to put in this format: "C:\\Desktop\\leitura.txt" But doesnt work.

Comment: My file name was "leitura.txt.txt" i put the format .txt on file name. Sorry, now working.

Answer (score 0):

You must include `stdlib.h` in your pre-compiler directives:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // missing library in your code

int main()
{
    FILE *arq = NULL;
    char c;
    int x;
    arq = fopen("leitura.txt", "r");
    if (arq == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    while (fscanf(arq, "%c", &c) != EOF)
    {
        printf("%c", c);
    }
    x = ftell(arq);
    printf("NUMBER OF BYTES: %d", x);
    fclose(arq);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may want to specify why `#include <stdlib.h>` is required. As far as I can tell, `exit` is the only function which requires this header, but OP's problem occurs before that function is called. Therefore, I don't think that this is the solution to the problem. But you are right that this `#include` directive should still be used anyway.

Comment: Then probably the issue is with the PATH to the file itself. To verify if that's the case, the OP should provide more information.

Comment: According to the comments section of the question, the problem has now been solved. It was a different issue.